# Function that is continuous in the irrationals but discontinuous in the rationals

Tags: analysis, continuity

If $x$ is rational then it is equal to $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers such that fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ is in lowest terms and $n>0$.

> Let $f(x)$ be defined to be equal $\frac{1}{n}$ if $x$ is rational. Otherwise, if $x$ is irrational, let $f(x)=0$.
>
> Why is this function continuous at irrationals?

I suppose it is the case that if you take smaller and smaller neighbourhoods of irrational $x$ then the rationals close to $x$ has bigger and bigger denominators. Is it true? Why is that?

Comment: For a rational number to get arbitrarily close to an irrational number, the denominator must go to infinity.

Comment: Your title is backwards!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}
$$
For each real number $\ \alpha\ $ and positive integer $\ n\ $, let $\ \epsilon_n(\alpha)\eqdef$$\,\min_\limits{p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\\n\ge q>0}\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|\ $. If $\ \alpha\ $ is irrational, then $\ \epsilon_{n}(\alpha)>0\ $, $\ \lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}\epsilon_{n}(\alpha)=0\ $, and if $\ \left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\epsilon_n(\alpha)\ $ with $\ p,q\in\mathbb{Z}\ $ and $\ q>0\ $, then by definition of $\ \epsilon_n(\alpha)\ $ we must have $\ q>n\ $.